# Angular chart is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am using Angular-chart. Below is my JS

```
  $scope.Fchart = {
        series: "Employer",
        data: [ {x:"abc",y:450},{x:"bcd",y:500},{x:"cds",y:350} ]
    };
```

My HTML look like below

```
<div ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="Fchart" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div>
```

Here is my App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','myApp.config','ui.select2','ngToast','angularCharts']);
```

When i run the application. I am getting undefined is not function in console. Also i am not getting the chart.

What went wrong ?

Can any one help me. Thanks,

Comment: have you included d3 library in your page

Comment: HI @ArunPJohny yes i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

series should be array : `series: ['Employer'],`

and `y` should be array `{x:"abc",y:[450]}`

```
$scope.Fchart = {
    series: ['Employer'],
    data: [
          {x:"abc",y:[450]},
          {x:"bcd",y:[500]},
          {x:"cds",y:[350]}
    ]
}
```

and you missing the chart type in `<div>`.

```
<div ac-chart="chartType" ... // have to replace the `chartType` with a chart type like `bar` , `pie`
```

then it should be like

```
<div ac-chart="'bar'".... //for bar chart.
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojWE4BNm7IdA7onGt124?p=preview)